# RuntimeError : dictionary changed size during iteration with defaultdict()

Tags: python

In the code I wrote, an error called **RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration** occurred in the **for i in graph** part. although I did not change the graph dictionary at all.  I experimented with this as well as if it wasn't possible to use defaultdict in the for statement, but it worked well, the code I experimented is also attached, so can I know why this error came out?

```
def canFinish(numCourses: int, prerequisites:[[]]) -> bool:
        
        graph = collections.defaultdict(list)
        visited = set()
        
        for i in prerequisites:
            graph[i[0]].append(i[1])
        
        def _dfs(i):
            if i in visited:
                return False
            
            visited.add(i)
            for e in graph[i]:
                if not _dfs(e):
                    return False
            visited.remove(i)
            return True
            
        
        
        for i in graph:
            if not _dfs(i):
                return False
            
        return True
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-33d660346b1a> in <module>
----> 1 canFinish(3, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]])

<ipython-input-36-fd2cb0d8dafb> in canFinish(numCourses, prerequisites)
     20 
     21 
---> 22         for i in graph:
     23             if not _dfs(i):
     24                 return False

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

experiment code

```
a = defaultdict(list)
a[1] = [3,4,5]
a[2]
for q in a:
    print(q)

"""
OUTPUT : 1,2
"""
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message and traceback?

Comment: Im sort of confused, the error you just edited in is very different then the error you are talking about in your post. I thought you were dealing with a `RuntimeError` and not a `NameError`? If it is just a `NameError` then make sure `from collections import defaultdict` is at the top of whatever `.py` file this is in.

Comment: @BeanBagTheCat I'm so sorry. I edited again

Answer (score 3):

I can see how your code can add items to `graph` inside the loop in question...

You are iterating over the items in `graph`.  So let's say `graph` looks like this:

```
graph = [g1, g2, g3]
```

So the loop calls `_dfs(g1)`.  Then, inside `_dfs`, there's this line:

```
for e in graph[i]:
```

so that line is iterating over `graph[g1]`.  That's fine, because that entry exists in `graph`.  But what is in `graph[g1]`?  We don't know.
Let's assume the first key in that collection is `x1`.  So now `e` is `graph[g1][x1]`.  Then, `_dfs` is called again, with this new `e`:

```
_dfs(e)
```

Then inside `_dfs`, we again do:

```
for e in graph[i]:
```

but this time `i` is `graph[g1][x1]`, the prior `e` that was passed in as the parameter to `_dfs`.  So this line is really:

```
for e in graph[graph[g1][x1]]
```

We don't know what `graph[g1][x1]` is. We can't assume that it is a key in `graph`.  If it isn't, then because `graph` is a `defaultdict`, an entry is added to `graph` for the key `graph[g1][x1]`, with an empty list as the key.  This is when `graph` changes size.

If `graph[g1][x1]` were already in `graph`, then I believe that this code would recurse forever.

I don't understand your logic since you haven't shown us the incoming data passed in as `prerequisites`.  Looking just at the code, I can't think of how calling `_dfs` recursively, and therefore needing items in the value lists of `graph` to also be keys in `graph`, would ever make sense.  I would suggest that you rethink this aspect of your algorithm.